# Mysql reliable with 1000 new entries / minute?

Tags: mysql

I have been developing an application that in the WORST case writes 1000 entries each minute into a database for over a year...

I wanted to use Mysql as DB, but I have read that with high datatransfers it becomes unreliable when writing. Is this true? Is 1000 entries considered a high amount of data? What would be such a high amount of data? Would corrupt data mean that I miss one entry or that I lose the whole table?

Thanks

Comment: 1000 per minute = 17 per second. Not very many. But ultimately it depends on your hardware and server load. Not a programming question as it stands.

Comment: My suggestion use any commercial database cause MySQL is open source and have some limitations and performance issues. My personal experience in one of my project, I found SQL express even faster than MySQL (SAME DATA, SAME SYSTEM and SAME PROCESS)

Comment: @JackGajanan MySQL runs better on Linux systems. We used MySQL in commercial setups and experienced no performance issues. And we saved six digits of licensing costs compared to other solutions.

Comment: What does mysql being open source have anything to do with it?

Comment: thanks guys for the answers. currently we are using mssql but it is limited to 2 years of data with the free license (based on the amount of data written and the max number of entries we can have). we need 10 years and the mssql licese costs way too much.

Comment: @JackGajanan - how long have you been in IT? 3 months?

Comment: what might happen is that the informations are written all toghether at the same time. would that be a huge problem? 1000 entries in a few secodns?

Comment: 14 years and 3 Universities are using my product in current condition: open source issue Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223738/create-view-statement-sequence-issue-in-exported-database-script-in-my-sql

Comment: It's sad that in 14 years you still display knowledge of a person who works in the field for 3 months. You actually have 0 idea of what you're talking about. Could you please get some information about the software you're using and the one you're comparing it with? It's simply gibberish what you wrote, it's sad to read.

Comment: In above case MYSQL will easily handle 1000 entries per second to store but will face serious problems while retrieving data as well with insertion.

Comment: i am in no way an expert on this. i tought that reading speed depends mainly on how you form the query and set the indexes.

Comment: May be my experience with MYSQL was exception but do you really compare complex queries with joins with other databases, I did and result was we shift our database to SQL Express to save cost but gain performance on that particular project.

Comment: @JackGajanan - no it won't, do you know the implication of providing false information? The performance, no matter what RDBMS you use is in the end in 99.9% cases due to HDD subsystem.

Comment: Any way that was my experience (TIME=COST basis) as I wrote above, that was my personal experience. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/product-info/competitor-compare.aspx#MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prrffzzt. No, this isn't exactly high write load.

You should test yourself with your own data, of course. It depends on the kind of write query, the size of the table, the type of keys you're using. [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)  is your friend.

We have used MySQL as a backend for a major social networking website (high write load) without reliability problems. You can build impressive setups (as in: racks of servers just running the database) with MySQL.

You should consider MariaDB since many of the original MySQL developers moved there. You should also consider hiring a consultant if you are really worried about optimization and if your current solution doesn't scale.

Comment: nope it doesnt scale. 1000 is really the worst case scenario. 500 is a more realistic value. what if they would be sent all toghether at the same time? meaning 1000 entries in a few seconds?

Comment: You have to test this yourself with your own data. And then finetune using EXPLAIN. You can easily create a table with keys that will slow down your server for every write entry, while another table setup will be fast.

Comment: thanks! could you please also answer the last sentence in the main question to be complete so i can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Btw, there is a special INSERT syntax that you can use to store multiple entries with one query. That way, the table key update will be done for all entries at once, significantly speeding up the database. We used this for one of our projects by simply queueing up entries using gearman, only doing INSERT when we had a few hundred entries queued up.

Comment: Also, obviously it depends on your hardware setup (CPU, RAM, OS) and the kind of table and keys/indices you are using. Again 1000/Minute isn't really exciting when it comes to databases, be it MySQL or any other out there. You should also consider if you really need a relational database. If all you really need is storage, you can also use a structured text file log dump. For analysis, you can then still try and compare various database engines later.

Comment: The recommended setup for your average high load MySQL system is a dedicated master-server. That one gets all the write queries. Plus one or more read-servers, using replication. You can then do whatever READ query you like on the read-servers and you can even have different keys on the read-servers, e.g. if you need a key for analysis READ queries without slowing down the master server that isn't used for analysis cron jobs. You have to deal with replication lag, though. The nice thing is that you can add read-servers as your system grows.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial by my colleague: http://vimeo.com/15837538 - it's from 2010, though, but it's still current for your problem.